# Missing package "metro" in the project at D:\ReactNative\FirstProject

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Missing package "metro" in the project at D:\ReactNative\FirstProject. This usually means `react-native` is not installed. Please verify that dependencies in package.json include "react-native" and run `yarn` or `npm install`.
Error: Missing package "metro" in the project at D:\ReactNative\FirstProject. This usually means `react-native` is not installed. Please verify that dependencies in package.json include "react-native" and run `yarn` or `npm install`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQdtz.png)

Comment: This question seems to be only an error message.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue after installing

`react-native-paper`

After follow this steps all worked again

1. Remove `node_modules` folder.
2. Install all dependencies again, run `npm install`. If show any error Remove `package-lock.json`.
3. Run `npm start` again.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 9):

you **don't really need to delete** node_modules folder.

just update it by typing:

1/ npm : `npm install`

or

2/ yarn : `yarn install`

in your terminal. That will update the node_modules folder content as well as creating all missing files without the need to reinstall it from scratch.

Answer (score 6):

I deleted the folder "node_modules" then run "npm install" again. It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue after I installed react-native-svg

Maybe there is some sort of naming conflict is causing this error? Deleting node_modules and running npm install again fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same problem, after running 'npm install --global expo-cli' it solved the issue or you can run npm install

Comment: How is this answer different from the others for this question?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue after installing @react-native-community/hooks

You don't need to delete any node_modules folder.

Installing react-native again solved the problem for me.

`npm i react-native`

Answer (score 2):

Try Using **npm i metro**

*Worked for me*

Answer (score 1):

try to start the project from main folder created by expo init.
i.e opening the project folder directly on you visual studio

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when you tried install @react-native/bottom-tabs. But I've installed this package with npm,  so I removed this package and installed it again with yarn and it fix my problem with no need to remove node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this problem based on how you created the program. So, when I created it from the terminal, following this instruction: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup it worked, but when I tried to create the program inside of the terminal in an existing project, I got the error.

Answer (score 0):

**installing expo and expo start working for me.**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33183550)

Answer (score -1):

I experienced the same issue, I'm using expo managed workflow, and cleaning `cache` has worked for me.

`expo r -c` is the command I used.